# Срабатывание события "click" при клике на пробел в firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

У меня есть кнопка, при клике на которую происходит какой-то функционал. Так если я кликну на пробел, то это событие тоже произойдет. preventDefault() применял - не работает. Это явление происходит только в браузере Firefox.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn-start">Начать</button>
```

**JS**

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-start');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Hello, world!'));
```

Comment: Странно, ну можно попробовать обработать саму кнопку, например если вызывалось событие для кнопки - пробел - 32 вроде, то не выполнять событие. Можно создать состояние типа isSpace и отслеживать нажатие, если пробел был, менять состояние, а у  click  писать условие на это состояние.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И в фаерфоксе и в хроме будет такой эффект, если фокус в данный момент на кнопке. Если допустим сначала мышкой нажали, потом пробел или enter.
Можно так избежать:

```
btn.addEventListener('keydown',e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Также можно убирать фокус с кнопки:

```
 btn.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        this.blur();
 })
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение! 2-ой вариант подошел

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не воспроизводится ни в одном из браузеров в которых пробовал. Возможно проблема в установленных расширениях или в остальном коде страницы.